# Entity Framework foreign key when name doesn't match

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table called `AccountValues` that I would like to reference from my `Account` table. However rather than using `AccountValuesId` and `AccountValues`, I would like it to be a little more descriptive by prefixing `MostRecent_` as follows:

```
[ForeignKey("AccountValues")]
public long MostRecent_AccountValuesId { get; set; }
public AccountValues MostRecent_AccountValues { get; set; }
```

My question is where should I place my `ForeignKey` attribute, so that I end up with an actual foreign key (e.g. `FK_Something`) and also have `MostRecent_AccountValues` automagically work?

Note: my convention is not to have plural table names. But here `AccountValues` is plural only because each row has a number of different values in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your `ForeignKey` name on the `public long MostRecent_AccountValuesId` property. `ForeignKey` name should match the navigation property name as follows:

```
[ForeignKey("MostRecent_AccountValues")] // <-- Here it is
public long MostRecent_AccountValuesId { get; set; }
public AccountValues MostRecent_AccountValues { get; set; }
```